# Generics: access object property using constraint 'where T : class' on generic method

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I apologize if this question has been covered elsewhere but I haven't been able to find an answer to it yet.

I am currently learning generics in C# and am fiddling with passing in a generic object reference to the following method which has a constraint on the type argument

```
public static T GetProperty<T>(T obj) where T : class
```

In this method I wish to access the `Isbn` property of the `Book` class (which I outline further below) but fail to see how to achieve this. E.g. in the body of the method `GetProperty<T>(T obj)` I wish to do something along the lines of:

```
public static T GetProperty<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    // How to access the passed in generic object's properties?
    // E.g. passing in an object of type Book, which has a property 'Isbn',
    // how do I return obj.Isbn?
}
```

For now the `GetProperty<T>(T obj)` method resides in a class called `Utilities`.

I have created a simple class for testing purposes:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Isbn { get; set; }
}
```

I create a new instance of `Book` and set the `Isbn` property:

```
Book book = new Book() { Isnb = 1234 };
```

I then call the `GetProperty()`method like so:

```
Utilities.GetProperty(book);
```

Thank you for your help or any reference to where I can resolve this question.

Comment: Will this function be called with types other than `Book`? If so, what do you want it to do? If not, then there's no need to make it generic at all, just change the argument type to `Book` instead of `T`.

Comment: Yes, the function will need to take any object type. Edit: What I want to do is search the passed in object for a predicate using a delegate.

Comment: If it can be any object, then it may not have an `.Isbn` property. What do you want the method to do if there is no such property?

Comment: That's a valid point. I guess I was wondering whether it would be possible to somehow figure out what object is passed in, look for a given property in that object (maybe passed in as a parameter in the method as well) and then return a bool saying that the property is in fact there. However, maybe this is a little bit _too_ generic of an approach...

Comment: If you're really going to inspect the object at runtime, generics won't help you. Just take an `object` argument and use reflection. But a better approach would be to either use an interface, or to create a delegate type for a function to extract the value you want.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong tool for your job. Consider either passing an interface or a base class. A generic method is more suitable to situations where you don't really care what that type is. If you do look for properties via reflection, you may for example look for an attribute on them (most serializers could be described in this way)

Comment: @DanielPryden OK. So if I for instance pass in a delegate `Func<T, bool> property` to the method, so the parameters to the method now will be `GetProperty<T>(T obj, Func<T, bool> property)`, you are saying I would then be able to find any given property in the object reference I pass in? Calling the method would then look like `book.GetProperty(x => x.Isbn == 1234);`

Comment: @kdhansen: Sure, you could do that, but in that case what value is this method adding? Why not just write `book.Isbn == 1234` directly? But one possibility is to pass the delegate in some other way. Or you could introduce a new interface, e.g. `IBook` or `IHasIsbn`, and make the `Book` class implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't unless you cast the `obj` to `Book` something like

```
(obj as Book)?.Isbn
```

Yes Reflection can be used but as commented above, not sure why you need a generic method in that case.

```
var property = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name = "Isbn").Select(p => p).
return obj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(obj, null);
```

Comment: So it is not possible to somehow (e.g. via Reflection) to fetch object Type and thereby access its properties? I need to be able to pass any object in, so casting it is not an option since the object will not be known beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use reflection here, 
I would use the T as the property type (result) and add a parameter propName

```
 public static T GetProperty<T>(Object obj,string propName) where T : class
    {
        return (T)src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the return type in your signature? obj return type could be anything, but not T

Answer (score 0):

Return Type should be same what you are expecting

```
public static int? GetProperty<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    bool isBook = (obj is Book);
    if(isBook)
    {
        var bookObj = (obj as Book);
        return ((bookObj != null) ? bookObj.Isbn : null);
    }
    return null;
}
```